# How to get a nokia phone (C7) to talk with a android phone (Nexus S) using NFC protocoles

Tags: android, qt, symbian, nokia, nfc

I've been developping a small game on symbian and android that sends messages using NFC.

I tried using many protocoles but still haven't been able to send even a small string (either via p2p or via tag detection) from the C7 to the nexus.

Can anyone tell me which protocole i should be using ?

Where could i find an example if such an example exists ?

Is it even possible to make the two interact ?

Thanks in advance and sorry if my english is a bit rusty.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should first take a look at existing NFC examples from Android and Nokia.

For example, Android has Beam Demo application - http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AndroidBeamDemo/index.html and Nokia has NFC Tag - http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/GUID-E35887BB-7E58-438C-AA27-97B2CDE7E069/GUID-DB3F8F61-CF5F-436F-9678-B5EADBB13999.html and NFC Share - http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/GUID-E35887BB-7E58-438C-AA27-97B2CDE7E069/GUID-5294D18E-E2BF-4723-BEFA-55C282F1F3DB.html example applications.

Try them first to check if they even can see and talk to each other.